# Iterate over methods

Tags: java, arrays, object-oriented-analysis

I am having some trouble with this `for` loop. I am not sure if I have correctly set up this method.

*Here is what it is asking me to do*

Iterate over all the elements in the subscribers array. You should use the easier version of 
the `for` loop to do this. Inside the loop: If the element is not equal to `null`, then call the 
`notify` method on that subscriber. When you call that method you need to give it a 
`Message` argument: use the same `Message` that was given to this method.
Note that here you are inside the `notify` method, and you're calling the `notify` method 
again. However, this is not recursion because the notify method you're calling is on a 
completely different `ISubscriber` instance.

```
package message;

public class Broadcaster implements IPublisher, ISubscriber {
    private Object [] members;
    private int i = 0;

    Broadcaster(int a) {
        a = 4;
        Object[] array = new Object[a];  
        members = array;    
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(ISubscriber subscriber) {
        members[i] = subscriber;       
        i++;   
    }

    @Override
    public void unsubscribe(ISubscriber subscriber) {
    }

    @Override
    public void notify(Message msg) {
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I am not sure if I have correctly set up this method."* I don't see a loop in your code so I guess you have not correctly set it up. What is your question?

Comment: I scrolled up and down two times, did I miss the loop?

Comment: You don't have a subscribers array. You are not looping on it using a `for` loop, and you are not calling each subscriber's `notify` method. Put some more effort in it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't use an Array for this but something dynamic. e.g. a LinkedList

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Broadcaster
{
    LinkedList<ISubscriber> subscribers = new LinkedList<ISubscriber>();

    public void subscribe(ISubscriber addMe)
    {
        if(addMe!= null)
        {
            if(! subscribers.contains(addMe))
            {
                this.subscribers.add(addMe);
            }
        }
    }

    public void unsubscribe(ISubscriber removeMe)
    {
        if(removeMe!= null)
        {
            this.subscribers.remove(removeMe);
        }
    }

    public void notifySubscribers() //this is called notify in your code
    {
        for(ISubscriber current : subscribers)
        {
            if(current != null)
            {
                current.beNotified(new Message());
            }
        }
    }
}

interface ISubscriber
{

    void beNotified(Message msg);    //also called notify for you; if possible avoid
}
```

If you are forced to use an array you get something like this:

```
public class Broadcaster
{
    int maxsubscribers = 4;
    ISubscriber[] subscribers = new ISubscriber[maxsubscribers];

    public void subscribe(ISubscriber addMe)
    {
        if(addMe != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <maxsubscribers;i++)
            {
                if(subscribers[i] != null)
                {
                    if(subscribers[i].equals(addMe))
                    {
                        return; //already in array; not adding 
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i <maxsubscribers;i++)
            {
                if(subscribers[i] == null)
                {
                    subscribers[i] = addMe;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void unsubscribe(ISubscriber removeMe)
    {
        if(removeMe != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <maxsubscribers;i++)
            {
                if(subscribers[i].equals(removeMe))
                {
                    subscribers[i] = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void notifySubscribers() //this is called notify in your code
    {
        for(ISubscriber current : subscribers)
        {
            if(current != null)
            {
                current.beNotified(new Message());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The downside of using an array is that you either can only store a certain number of elements or have to change the size of the array as soon as you run out of free slots.

As you can see it is also a bit harder to avoid that subscribers are added twice to the array. It requires an addition loop just to check this while the LinkedList offers a convenient method for this check.

And last but not least: While it is possible to have a `notify()` and a `notify(Message msg)` method that do entirely different things this is not good practice as it can easily lead to mixing up the functions.